# Dynamically get version of Vaadin Flow in running web app

Tags: version, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In a [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow) app, how does one ask what version of Vaadin is currently deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Version`

You can find that information from Flow's [`Version`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/com/vaadin/flow/server/Version.html) class.

```
System.out.println( "Vaadin Version.getFullVersion(): " + Version.getFullVersion() );
```